# Replacing two variables after filling a form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm not much of a Javascript expert, but sometimes I need to turn to it.
I have a script which allows the user to choose two dates (from and to) to create a report.

```
<div onmouseover="myFunction()">
<input id="id_from_date" name="from_date" type="text">
<input id="id_to_date" name="to_date" type="text">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    $('#id_from_date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd-m-Y',
        lang: 'pl',
        pickTime: false,
        timepicker: false,
        weeks: true,
        dayOfWeekStart: 1,
        closeOnDateSelect: true
    });
    $('#id_to_date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd-m-Y',
        lang: 'pl',
        pickTime: false,
        timepicker: false,
        weeks: true,
        dayOfWeekStart: 1,
        closeOnDateSelect: true
    });
    var from = document.getElementById("id_from_date").value;
    var to = document.getElementById("id_to_date").value;
    var url = '{% url 'logistyka_tabela_brakow.views.report_from_to' '11-11-1111' '12-12-1212' %}';
    document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", url.replace(/11-11-1111/, from), url.replace(/12-12-1212/, to))
}
</script>

 <a id="link" type="button" class="btn btn-success">go!</a>
```

I'm at the end of my tether here. The code replaces the first variable, id_from_date, with the date a user chooses. Unfortunately, it ignores the second variable, id_to_date. Can anyone please give me a hint why it happens so? 
I cannot leave var url withour any initial values, because the application crashes without anything given while opening the view.
The whole project is created in Django and the view for the report is:

```
def report_from_to(request, from_date, to_date):
    from datetime import datetime
    strfrom = datetime.strptime(from_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
    strto = datetime.strptime(to_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
    report = Braki.objects.filter(Q(date__gte=strfrom), Q(date__lte=strto))
    return render(request, 'logistyka_tabela_brakow/report_from_to.html', {'report': report})
```

the form:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    from_date = forms.DateField()
    to_date = forms.DateField()
    fields = '__all__'
```

the url is obviously:

```
url(r'report_from_to/(?P<from_date>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/(?P<to_date>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})',
               'logistyka_tabela_brakow.views.report_from_to', name='report_from_to'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax of setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is

```
element.setAttribute(name, value);
```

You are calling it with 3 arguments, so the third one gets ignored.

```
document.getElementById("link")
  .setAttribute("href", 
                url.replace(/11-11-1111/, from),
                url.replace(/12-12-1212/, to)
  );
```

This should do it

```
var url = '{% url 'logistyka_tabela_brakow.views.report_from_to' '11-11-1111' '12-12-1212' %}';
url = url.replace(/11-11-1111/, from);
url = url.replace(/12-12-1212/, to);
document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", url);
```